# How do I update the data associated with a QListWidgetItem from the QListWidget in PyQt?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a `QListWidget` that has 10 `QListWidgetItems`. When each of those `QListWidgetItems` is created I do something like this:

```
item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem("Text to Show")
item.setData(36, "A specific value that is used later")
self.ui.my_list.addItem(item)
```

Now, later in the application, after a user clicks a button, I want to update the text "A specific value that is used later", for the item that is selected. I have attempted to do this

```
ndx = self.ui.my_list.currentRow()
self.ui.my_list.item(ndx).setData(36, "Updated!")
```

The problem is, this doesn't work. It doesn't throw any errors, but the data is just gone. In my button press signal I have this code to see the value before and after the reassignment:

```
ndx = self.ui.my_list.currentRow()   
print "Before:", self.ui.my_list.item(ndx).data(36).toPyObject()
self.ui.my_list.item(ndx).setData(36, "Updated!")
print "After:", self.ui.my_list.item(ndx).data(36).toPyObject()
```

This outputs:

```
Before: A specific value that is used later
After:
```

How can I properly change the data so that it is saved back to the `QListWidgetItem`?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. I can imagine two sources of error: because your `QListWidgetItem` is connected to a `QListWidget`, maybe you have something connected to the change-signal which overwrites the value. What happens if you use a `QListWidgetItem` which is not connected to a list-view? For me, it works: http://pastebin.com/VSUithwZ Or maybe there is something funny going on with the `QVariant`-conversion. What are their types?

Comment: It's part of a larger application, so just a stand alone QListWidgetItem isn't feasible. I have tried with both a dictionary (as the full application uses) and a string for the stripped down example I posted here. Both are showing the same result.

Comment: I do not have any signals connected to the ListWidget yet.

Comment: What about the code I wrote? Does it work in your setup? If not, what's your Qt version?

Comment: I have QT Version 4.8.6 and PyQt version 4.9.6

Comment: @NewGuy. I cannot reproduce this. I tested using PyQt-4.9.5, PyQt-4.10, and PyQt-4.11.4 with Qt-4.8.7. It would seem that there may be a bug in the specific version of PyQ4 you are using. Have you tested with a completely stripped down, minimal example that just creates a list-widget with one item? You need to do that in order to isolate the problem and confirm it is a bug in PyQt4 rather than a bug in your own program.